# One to Many Mapping in hibernate with inheritance

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping

I have a Question super class with two sub classes SCQ and MCQ which is based on type(field present in Question table). I am trying to save value in Scq using spring boot but is throwing not null constraint error.

```
@Entity
   @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
   @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
    
    public class Question{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "qid", columnDefinition = "bigint")
    private Long qid;

    private String title;

    @Column(name = "type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String type;

}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SCQ")
public class Scq extends Question {

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Choice> choices;

}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("MCQ")
public class Mcq extends Question {

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Choice> choices;

}
```

This is the Choice entity.

```
@Entity
    @TypeDefs({ @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class),
            @TypeDef(name = "list-array", typeClass = ListArrayType.class) })
    public class Choice implements Serializable {
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5275536507460225258L;
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        private Long cid;
    
        @NotNull(message = ErrorMessage.TITLE_REQUIRED)
        private String title;
    
        @Type(type = "jsonb")
        @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
        private Image image;
    
        @Type(type = "list-array")
        @Column(name = "categories", columnDefinition = "text[]")
        private List<String> categories;
    
        private Boolean is_correct;
    
        @Transient
        private Integer ans_percent;
    
        @Transient
        private Boolean is_selected;
    
        @Transient
        private String hint;
    
        public Choice() {
            super();
        }
    
        public Choice(@NotNull(message = "Title is required.") String title, Boolean is_correct) {
            super();
            this.title = title;
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for saving Scq

```
@PostMapping(UrlPath.ADMIN_QUESTION_SCQ)
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> addQuestionScq(@Valid @RequestBody Scq scq) {
        if (scq.getCategory() == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse(Error.INVALID_DATA, "Category is required"));
        }
        // Check if its a valid category
        QuestionCategory category = QuestionCategory.valueOf(scq.getCategory());
        if (category == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse(Error.INVALID_DATA, "Category is wrong"));
        }

        scq = scqRepository.save(scq);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse(scq));
    }
```

When I am trying to save a value in SCQ I get the error

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "mcq_qid" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (6630, 6631, null).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:130)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 96 more
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code that performs this save that results in NPE? I reproduced your Entities as posted in your question (without the  `private List<Choice> choices;` however) and saving them (both Mcq and Scq) is successful. Can you also post the `Choice` entity class?

Comment: Moreover the error `null value in column "mcq_qid"` is not in accordance with the single table inheritance strategy. According to single table inheritance all entities are persisted on the same table and they share the same id column, in your case it should be `qid`. `mcq_id` doesn't seem correct. Are you sure you have posted the code that reflects to the error?

Comment: @pleft I have updated the question with the code for save and Choice entity.